# LookupError in NLTK for WordNet Lemmatizer Despite Successful Download of Resources

Tags: python, nltk, kaggle, lemmatization

I am working on a text processing task in a Kaggle notebook and facing a `LookupError`when using NLTK's `WordNetLemmatizer`. Despite my efforts to download the required NLTK resources, the error continues to occur. Below, I have provided the details of my preprocessing function, the error message, and the steps I've taken to resolve the issue.

Preprocessing Function:

```
def preprocess_str_ml(txt):
    tokenizer = TweetTokenizer()
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    
    # convert all characters in the string to lower case
    txt = txt.lower()
    # remove non-english characters, punctuation and numbers
    txt = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', txt)
    
    # Tokenize the text
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(txt)

    # Lemmatization and removing stop words
    lemmatized_tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
    
    txt = ' '.join(lemmatized_tokens)
    
    txt = remove_stop_words(txt)
    
    return txt
```

Error Message:

```
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py:80, in LazyCorpusLoader.__load(self)
     79 except LookupError as e:
---> 80     try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
     81     except LookupError: raise e

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/data.py:653, in find(resource_name, paths)
    652 resource_not_found = '\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (sep, msg, sep)
--> 653 raise LookupError(resource_not_found)

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource 'corpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/.zip/' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

1. I have tried downloading the complete NLTK package using `nltk.download("all")`.
2. I also attempted downloading the `"averaged_perceptron_tagger"`, as some forums suggested.
   These attempts were made within a Kaggle notebook environment.Despite these efforts, the error remains unresolved.

How can I effectively resolve this `LookupError`in the Kaggle notebook environment? Are there additional steps or configurations required for setting up NLTK for lemmatization with the WordNet Lemmatizer in Kaggle?

Comment: That's not the full traceback. Which line in your own code is implicated in the traceback? Please [edit] to provide all the debugging information.